# Standing and seating capacity of clubs, bars and restaurants

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, business

I'm looking for a dataset containing the following:

- Name of the business (I'm mostly interested in clubs, bars and restaurants) if possible along with its location
- Standing and [seating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seating_capacity) capacity

I'm mostly interested in the US and in particular, Boston and California.

Answer (score 5):

I've only came across one dataset that contained the seating capacity. It is the restaurant inspections for Seattle and King County:

http://info.kingcounty.gov/health/ehs/foodsafety/inspections/search.aspx